# How to get rid of background on exportable symbols in Sketch?

Tags: export, sketch-app, symbols

I have a symbol in sketch which I need to export. Whenever I make it exportable, it generates a large rectangular background to the symbol, which is not what I want. I want the symbol only as a png with no background.

I've never had this problem in the past, it usually just exports properly. I did, however, just upgrade to Sketch V.52, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

How do I get rid of the background? Thank you!!

[image: The symbol I'm trying to export]

[image: How it looks when it's exported]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch 52 now include Artboard's background export options to all layers presents in the artboard.

You should **disable "Include in export" background option in the Artboard** containing your symbol in order to get rid of larger background in symbol export.

[image]